# Javascript reloading list each time event is fired - Google Drive Realtime API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I have a collaborative list in google's realtime api, which is displayed in a select tab.

Currently I have this.

```
var managment = (function($) {


var deadline1 = undefined;
// the name of the authenticated user - once authentication has succeeded
var username = "unkown";
var realtimeLoader = undefined;

var initializeModel = function(model) {
    var deadline1 = model.createList();
    model.getRoot().set('deadline1', deadline1);

}

var onProjectsLoaded = function(doc) {

    deadline1 = doc.getModel().getRoot().get('deadline1');
    deadline1.addEventListener(gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.VALUES_ADDED, updateUi);
    deadline1.addEventListener(gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.VALUES_REMOVED, updateUi);
    deadline1.addEventListener(gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.VALUES_SET, updateUi);

    $("#inviteId").removeAttr("disabled");
    var inviteButton = $("#invite");
    inviteButton.removeAttr("disabled");
    inviteButton.click(inviteUser);


    var saveButton = $("#save");
    saveButton.click(addProject);

    var updateButton = $("#demoListSet");
    updateButton.click(onSetItems);

    var selector = $("#demoListInput");
    selector.change(onSelect);


}

var addProject = function() {
    var title = $("#title").val();
    var date = $("#datepicker").val();
    var priority = $("#priority").val();
    var description = $("#description").val();
    deadline1.push( {
    title : title,
    date : date,
    description : description,
    priority : priority,
    } );
}

var updateUi = function(evt) {
    /*$("#demoListInput").empty();*/
    var projectList = $("#demoListInput");
    for (var index in evt.values) {
    var deadline1 = evt.values[index];
    var newOption = $("<option>").val(deadline1.title).text("Title: " + deadline1.title + "  Date:"  + deadline1.date + " Priority: " + deadline1.priority)
    }
    projectList.append(newOption);
}
```

My problem is with the updateUI function.

The list is called deadline1. When an item is added to the list, it updates the list but the view of this list in the select tab, This is because I am only looping through the evt.values when displaying new items. What I would like to do it delete the current view of the list each time an event is fired (see the line currently in comment), however, every time I try and call deadline1 to loop through the length of it, it comes back saying deadline1 is undefined. Is there a way to get around this? Thank you.

Comment: this is what happens when you declare the same variable name multiple times...

Comment: So it does, that you. Changed the names and now seems to work

Comment: and that's how you learn :)